# Lost internet in raspbian, dhcpcd not found, can't use apt-get

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager

In my raspberry pi 3, I ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove network-manager network-manager-gnome openvpn openvpn-systemd-resolved network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

After that, I lost internet connection, I can't see wlan0 anymore on ifconfig...

I can't find any /etc/dhcpcd.conf file

Now, I could reinstall network-manager and network-manager-gnome with USB, but I still don't have internet. I can see wlan0 when I do `ifconfig`, but it has no ip.

When I try to set wifi country, it says:

```
Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant
```

I don't really know how to solve this one...

Comment: Did you used network manager before? network manager isn't supported by Raspbian by default. Do you use Raspbian?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that just the systemd-file for dhcpcd is missing. Is there a `dhcpcd` on the system? Try `ls /sbin`. If so, try the following:

1) In `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, put:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.178.53/24
static routers=192.168.178.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.178.6
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.178.3/24
static routers=192.168.178.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.178.6
```

(replace the IP adresses of the server, gateway and name server with your own)

2) in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` put the following

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="ssidforwifi"
    psk="wifipsk"
}
```

(replacing the ssid and psk with your own)

3) Make sure the systemd-service file exists in `/etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd5.service`; it should contain:

```
[Unit]
Description=dhcpcd on all interfaces
Wants=network.target
Before=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/dhcpcd.pid
ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -b
ExecStop=/sbin/dhcpcd -x

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=dhcpcd5.service
```

and 4) cycle the dhcpcd.

If not, create a `wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
network={
    ssid="yourSSID"
    psk="youtPSK"
    priority=1
}
```

And then:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode managed
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 essid 'yoyrSSID'
iwconfig wlan0 ap 00:11:22:33:44:55

wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0  -c./wpa_supplicant.conf
```

If `iwconfig` or `wpa_supplicabnt` are missing, you will not be able to set-up WiFi. Try to connect with a cable, even if it's just temporarily.

Failing that, I would suggest taking out the SD card and on a different computer:

- backup all user data
- re-install Raspian (or your favourite distro)
- restore tha user-data

And move from a clean installation.

Comment: Please read also the headline. There is **no dhcpcd**. And the OP seems not like to answer questions to clarify it.

Comment: Right. Sorry. Edited the answer accordingly.